# Accelerometer sensor gy-61 convert to m/s2

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I have a problem calibrating my GY-61 accelerometer on an Arduino Uno to get values in m/s2.

Analog-reading code:

```c
const int xPin = A5;         
const int yPin = A4;                
const int zPin = A3;
// ...
void loop() {
   int xRead = analogRead(xPin);
   int yRead = analogRead(yPin);
   int zRead = analogRead(zPin);

   float xData = (((float)xRead - 337.92) / 61.44 * 9.81);

   accData= sqrt((xData*xData)+(yData*yData)+(zData*zData));
```

xData should show values in m/s2.
What do those values  `337.92`  and  `61.44` mean and how can I calibrate them to get right values?

Values I get (in one position without moving):

```
xData   yData   zData    accData
-11.16   1.61   -0.79    11.31
-0.79  -11.48    0.01    11.51
-0.47   -0.63  -10.68    10.71
```

accData should be near 9.81 m/s2, also x or y or z, depending on rotation.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem ?

Comment: I get some answers on other forums, [this](http://sailboatinstruments.blogspot.si/2011/08/improved-magnetometer-calibration.html) and [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adxl345-digital-accelerometer/programming) . Second solution is better, but i still get strange readings. So i ordered some new acc sensors for testing, one of them is ADXL 335, which have many libraries and instructions. But still want to figure it out about GY-61.